# i can't use ListName.insert() function it said ListIndex error

Tags: python, python-3.x

i'm not in computer science or computer related major. i'm civil engineering student, and i'm trying to make app to ease my calculation that can't be calculated by spreadsheet. i know python basic. and please don't be cruel to me haha

so i have this code

```
from math import ceil

print('Masukan jarak antar pias')
jarakAntarPias = float(input())
print('Masukan kedalaman sondir')
kedalamanSondir = float(input())

jumlahTitik = int(ceil(kedalamanSondir/jarakAntarPias+1))
conus = []

cn2a = []
cn3a = []

for i in range(0, jumlahTitik):
    a = float(input())
    if a < 0:
        b = float(input())
        conus[i-1] = [(i-1)*jarakAntarPias, b]
        a = float(input())
    if a >= 0:
        conus.insert(i, [i*jarakAntarPias, a])


conusAtas = []
conusBawah = []

print(conus)
diameter = float(input())
d4 = diameter*4
d8 = diameter*8

y = 0
a1 = 0
while y <= jumlahTitik:
    if (d4/jarakAntarPias+1) >= y:
        while a1 <= y:
            conusAtas.insert(a1, conus[y-a1][1])
            a1 += 1
    else:
        while a1 <= (int((d4/jarakAntarPias))+1):
            conusAtas.insert(a1, conus[int((d4/jarakAntarPias))+1-a1][1])
            a1 += 1
    a1 = 0
    print(conusAtas)

    if (d8/jarakAntarPias+1) <= jumlahTitik-y:
        while a1 <= jumlahTitik-y:
            conusBawah.insert(a1, conus[y+a1][1])
            a1 += 1
    else:
        while a1 <= (d8/jarakAntarPias+1):
            conusBawah.insert(a1, conus[y+a1][1])
            a1 += 1
    #more code below
    print(conusBawah)
    conusAtas = []
    conusBawah = []
    y += 1
```

my problem is, the code works flawlessly as i expected if i didn't add this code

```
if (d8/jarakAntarPias+1) <= jumlahTitik-y:
    while a1 <= jumlahTitik-y:
        conusBawah.insert(a1, conus[y+a1][1])
        a1 += 1
else:
    while a1 <= (d8/jarakAntarPias+1):
        conusBawah.insert(a1, conus[y+a1][1])
        a1 += 1
```

those code actually similar like this code below

```
if (d4/jarakAntarPias+1) >= y:
    while a1 <= y:
        conusAtas.insert(a1, conus[y-a1][1])
        a1 += 1
else:
    while a1 <= (int((d4/jarakAntarPias))+1):
        conusAtas.insert(a1, conus[int((d4/jarakAntarPias))+1-a1][1])
        a1 += 1
```

but when the program is running this code

```
conusBawah.insert(a1, conus[y+a1][1])
```

it always have ListIndex error

this is the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/afahm/PycharmProjects/untitled2/DULS.py", line 56, in <module>
conusBawah.insert(a1, conus[y+a1][1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

please help me, i've been stuck in this code for two days.
thanks

Comment: can you provide a stack trace? as well as sample input?

Comment: did you try debugging into it? check how big `conus` actually is and which index you are trying to access with `y+a1`

Comment: what is stack trace? is that something that console say when error is occured?

Comment: @TobiasR yes i did, but it keep saying that list index is out of range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add a condition to all of your while statements where you use `conus[y+a1]`, because `y + a1` is bigger that the length of `conus`.

so... it would look like:

```
if (d4/jarakAntarPias+1) >= y:
    while a1 <= y and (y+a1) < len(conus):
        conusAtas.insert(a1, conus[y-a1][1])
        a1 += 1
else:
    while a1 <= (int((d4/jarakAntarPias))+1) and (int((d4/jarakAntarPias))+1-a1) < len(conus):
        conusAtas.insert(a1, conus[int((d4/jarakAntarPias))+1-a1][1])
        a1 += 1
a1 = 0
print(conusAtas)

if (d8/jarakAntarPias+1) <= jumlahTitik-y:
    while a1 <= jumlahTitik-y and (y+a1) < len(conus):
        conusBawah.insert(a1, conus[y+a1][1])
        a1 += 1
else:
    while a1 <= (d8/jarakAntarPias+1) and (y+a1) < len(conus):
        conusBawah.insert(a1, conus[y+a1][1])
        a1 += 1
```

This checks that the length `conus` is less than `y + a1`. eg. if `conus  = [[0.0, 3.0], [1.0, 4.0], [2.0, 5.0]]`  the `len(conus)` would be 3. you where getting the `IndexError`, is because `y +a1` was `3`, and because `conus is Zer0 indexed that would mean that`conus[2] == [2.0, 5.0]`. in other words`conus[3]` would fail.

Comment: WTF STRANGER??!!! U DID IT!!!. BIG THANKS FROM ME! HOPE YOU BECOME MORE SUCCESSFUL!!!. *still dont know why it works*

Comment: wouldn't this just catch the aftereffects of a logical error?

Comment: @TobiasR. how do you mean? This would check that the `y + a1` is never >   length of `conus`. There is perhaps a better solution?

Comment: The fact that he trys to access an index which doesnt exists, tells me there is some kind of "logical error". Your solution is some kind of "Hey, only run this part of code if it is going to work!" - which feels a bit more like a try/catch than a fix of his code. But maybe im wrong with this, its still early in the morning and i didnt review the whole code. :)

Comment: agree with renier y+a1 never bigger than length of conus. but it works!

Comment: @TobiasR. I see what you are saying, and I don't think you are wrong. As I've said, there might be a better solution that I can't see right now.

Answer (score 1):

In this iteration you are filling your list:

```
for i in range(0, jumlahTitik):
```

which means, your highest index is `jumlahTitik - 1`

in this iteration you are trying to access your list:

```
while y <= jumlahTitik:
```

On your last iterarion `y` would be `jumlahTitik` and `a1` would be >0

so `conus[y+a1]` trys to access `conus[jumlahTitik + a1]` which cant work, since your highest index is `jumlahTitik - 1`